# What is a good book for uniform spaces using pseudometrics definition?

Tags: book-recommendation, uniform-spaces

I want to learn uniform spaces. I like pseudometrics definition. Is there a book on uniform spaces using pseudometrics definition? The famous the better. I know most of the core subjects in undergraduate math.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36999/a-good-place-to-read-about-uniform-spaces

Comment: @Michael Thanks. NLab (recommended in the first answer) seems to be more readible than wikipedia. But it would be better if it uses a pseudometric definition, since that is what I am the most familiar with.

Comment: See Chapter 20 (pp. 172-190) of [**Topological Structures**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0030531403) by Wolfgang Joseph Thron (1966) and Chapter 11 (pp. 174-196) of [**Foundations of General Topology**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/148321172X) by William Joseph Pervin (1964). Also, there is a lot of detailed material on uniform spaces throughout [**General Topology**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/9630509709) by Ákos Császár (1978) (NOT to be confused with his 1963 **Foundations of General Topology**).